# How can I extract data from alamofire in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to extract **JSON** from request so I can use it in my code. But `nil` is returned(Actual string in console is `And here is JSON nil`)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var myVar: AnyObject?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get")
            .responseJSON { _, _, JSON, _ in
            self.myVar = JSON
        }
        println("And here is JSON \(self.myVar)")
    }
}
```

What have I to do to solve the problem ?

Comment: From https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire: *"Networking in Alamofire is done **asynchronously**. Asynchronous programming may be a source of frustration to programmers unfamiliar with the concept, but there are very good reasons for doing it this way. Rather than blocking execution to wait for a response from the server, a callback is specified to handle the response once it's received. **The result of a request is only available inside the scope of a response handler.** Any execution contingent on the response or data received from the server must be done within a handler."*

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to understand whether the call is asynchronous. If so, there is no result when you execute `println`. You can put your `println` inside the result block like this:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get")
.responseJSON { _, _, JSON, _ in
    self.myVar = JSON
    println("And here is JSON \(self.myVar)")
}
```

Comment: sorry, Im new to iOS and programming at all, so im not familar with some concepts.

Comment: You need to look it up what's async and non-async networking call. @AlexeyK

Comment: according to your example it prints ok, but i cant store JSON result in variable. IS there any way to do this if printing is possible ?

Comment: What do you mean by that? What kind of data type is that? `[AnyObject:AnyObject]` or `[AnyObject]`?

Comment: made this work by trying.I have one question - i dont have anywhere variable MyQuests inside function or closure but it prints ok.  Can you please describe why is it happens so ?
    
        func getQuests(completionHandler: (NSDictionary) -> Void) {
            Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get").responseJSON { _, _, json, _ in
                completionHandler(json as! NSDictionary)
            }
        }
        
        var myQuests: NSDictionary?
        
        getQuests() { quests in myQuests = quests
            println("My Quests: \(myQuests)")
        }

Comment: U need to tell compiler what data type it's. Otherwise, it will think that it's AnyObject type and it doesn't know how to match it.